# Верстка макета, простая задача, но мозг отказывается работать

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Доброго времени суток!
То ли лето, то мне пора в отпуск, но что-то я заглумился с одним макетом. Дизайнеры люди творческие, и всякие штуки придумывают, вот попался мне макет и ломаю голову я, хотя опыта верстки хоть отбавляй. Может посоветуете что нить. Такая задача:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

серый 1 и 2 участки - это меню и футер, тут ничего специфичного, далее желтая область блок с текстом, высота динамическая, в зависимости сколько напишут, всегда должен быть одной ширины и центрироваться по вертикале относительно малинового 4 блока. 4 малиновый блок - занимает всю оставшуюся часть, внутри содержит слайдер изображений, при изменений размеров экрана должен уменьшаться в ширине кадрируя картинку, и 5 это рамочка, которая ровно по контуру огибает 3й блок(с учетом динамической высоты 3го блока) и заходит на картинку, как показано на скрине, при изменений экрана всегда имеет ровные отступы справа и слева.
Вот как все реализовать без js ума не приложу, а с js мне кажется не совсем кошерная верстка. Вот собственно задача, сильно не пинайте, либо переработал либо лето сказывается.
Буду рад советам.

Comment: Вы начните, а мы поможем, а если вопрос ставить так - то фриланс в помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос, полагаю, скорее всего не актуален. Но из спортивного интереса попробовал сделать. Получилось без каких-либо сильных заморочек, но с небольшими ограничениями. Верстка исключает скролл, почти все размеры и отступы в процентах, высота контента боковушки по идее не должна превысить дозволенного ему места.

http://jsfiddle.net/fycfyvjq/

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content">

    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20%;"></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="image"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="inner-wrapper">
                        <div class="inner-left">
                            <div class="text-left">111 <br> 222</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inner-right">
                                <div class="text-right"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
html, body{height: 100%;}
body{margin: 0;}
table{width: 100%; height: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;}
table td{padding: 0; height: 100%;}

.wrapper{height: 100%;}
.header, .footer{height: 10%; background: #818181;}
.content{position: relative; height: 80%;}
.image{height: 100%; background: rgba(237, 0, 140, 0.2);}
.text{height: 100%; border: 1px solid grey; border-right: 0;}
.text-right{height: 100%; border: 1px solid grey; border-left: 0;}
.table-wrapper{position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; height: 100%;}
.inner-wrapper{position: relative;}
.inner-left{float: left; width: 20%; padding-left: 2%; height: 100%; position: relative;}
.inner-right{float: right; width: 80%; padding-right: 2%; height: 100%; position: absolute; right: 0;}
.text-left{border: 1px solid grey; border-right: 0; padding: 20px; background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);}
.text-right{border: 1px solid grey; border-left: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
.header,.footer{
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 background:lightgrey;
 position:relative;
 top:0;
}
.wrapper{
 width:100%;
 min-height:500px;
 background:;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.wrapper .aside,.article{
 float:left;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 min-height:500px;
}
.aside{
  width:25%;
  background:#f1f1f1;
}
.article{
  width:75%;
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <header class="header">
 
 </header>
 <div class="wrapper">
   <aside class="aside">
   
   </aside>
   <article class="article">
   
   </article>
 </div>
 <footer class="footer">
 
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

вроде бы так -- посмотрите

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!, но вы немного не правильно поняли. 5ть - это не блок, а рамка, которая должна опоясывать два блока - желтый и малиновый, а блок 4 не ограничевается рамкой под номером 5ть, блок 4е это все малинового цвета, получается большой блок со слайдером - малиновый, блок поменьше - желтый, с текстом, центрируется по вертикали, относительного малинового, а рамка, опоясывает из как на скрине. При этом у желтого блока фиксированная ширина, а у малиновый жмется по высоте.

Comment: я просто не совсем въехал - малиновый он другой высоты что ли ?

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5EzL/KMZUjGij6  вот скачай это , там архив - в нём вёрстка - посмотри -- больше не буду верстать , надоело

Comment: спасибо вам за труды. Но вы не много не по теме, мне нужен не просто двух колоночный макет.

Comment: я не понимаю ваше желание - в моде минимализм , а городьба - лишнее , две или три колонки -- это нормально , больше (из моего опыта ) не надо не кому

Comment: я прослежу за вашим вопросом и особенно за ходом его решения , 100% что решение есть -- но тогда надо лучше объяснять , вы как нарисовали -- но там не видно не фига -- получается розовый больше того что №4 но он находится на этом номере -- я не понял не хрена

Comment: номер 4 это слайдер, который занимает все розовое пространство, желтый блок с текстом меньше розового, и центрируется по вертикали, причет высота динамическая, а 5 - это просто рамка, черная прямоуголяная рамка, располагающаяся так как показано на схеме, а именно полностью в себя поглащает желтый блок, и только часть розового